# Getting contents of dynamic Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, setinterval

I am trying to get the contents of a dynamically generated Iframe (same-domain). I have this so far.

```
 var frame = $('#avacweb_chat iframe');
 var time = $('.date-and-time' , frame.contents()).last().attr('title');
 var getTime = setInterval(function() {
    var newTime = $('.date-and-time , frame.contents()').last().attr('title');
 },500);
```

I tried lines 1 and 2 together with an alert of `time` to see if I was actually grabbing the data. Though I am not. Basically what I want to do is get the last message `.data-and-time` and with the setInterval get the same thing.

If they are different do something.

This is how I believe my code will be set up once i get the data

```
 var frame = $('#avacweb_chat iframe');
 var time = $('.date-and-time' , frame.contents()).last().attr('title');
 var getTime = setInterval(function() {
    var newTime = $('.date-and-time , frame.contents()').last().attr('title');
 },500);
   if(time === newTime) {
       alert();
     }
```

Any suggestions on grabbing data from iframe?

Also tried=

```
var frame = $('#avacweb_chat iframe');
var time = $(frame).contents($('.date-and-time'));
alert(time.length);
```

Which I get 1 which is correct

Then I tried

```
var frame = $('#avacweb_chat iframe');
var time = $(frame).contents($('.date-and-time').attr('title'));
alert(time);
```

Which becomes `[object Object]`

Working code =

```
   var frame = $('#avacweb_chat iframe');
   var time = $('.date-and-time' , frame.contents()).last().attr('title');
   var newTime = setInterval(function() {
   var newT = $('.date-and-time' , frame.contents()).last().attr('title');
   },500);
    if(time !== newT) {
      alert('New Message');
    }
```

Now my question would be how do I get the newTime store it and then compare them?

Comment: what is this `, frame.contents()')` .. Looks like it is not a valid selector !!

Comment: Is the iframe src on your domain? Cause if not, the Same Origin Policy is about to ruin your day. EDIT: just saw you said same domain at the top.

Comment: Same Origin yes ;) and Sushanth I was reading other questions on how to get data from iframe and they say to do that, that is why I did that... is this wrong?

Comment: `var newTime = $('.data-and-time' , frame.contents()).last().attr('title');` should fix it at least partially. The `frame.contents()` shouldn't be in the string. It's a second argument.

Comment: `'frame.contents()'` is a string, it does not get the frame's contents.

Comment: Fixed it that was my bad. Also updated with some more codes that i've tried Kevin

Comment: @JakeM any other suggestions as I am either getting undefined or object Object

Comment: "I get 1 which is correct" => so it's working, right?

Comment: Its getting that there is one message. But it won't fetch any of the other data like Title or even text of the element to filter out the usersname

Comment: try $(frame).contents($('.data-and-time')).attr('title') (you have the parentheses mixed up)

Comment: @Christophe no because this alerts the title of the frame itself.

Comment: @Christophe please see updated code at the end

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a race condition. Would it be possible that your iFrame hasn't completely loaded at the time you're trying to traverse the DOM? Give this a shot:

```
var frame = $('#avacweb_chat iframe'),
    newTime;
frame.on('load', function(){
    newTime = frame.contents().find('.date-and-time').attr('title');
});
alert(newTime);
```

Comment: This would be an ajax request correct? Which we shouldn't need. The page is loaded as I'm debugging while in console, I haven't place the code in hard yet just console testing. So this wouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Please see updated code as I resolved this now I just need to compare

Comment: Yea, you're right. The new implementation of the .load() method is for retrieving data from the server. I didn't realize it was depreciated as of jQuery 1.8. What i meant was that you should probably wait for the iFrame to load by binding a 'load' event to it before trying to grab anything from it. I gather that you're using setInterval as a way to do that.

Take another peek at my previous answer. I've updated it with my correction.

Comment: Yeah it sucks when they take things out, that is one reason we should always keep up with the documentation. thank you for the update.